# BUNDLE_WITHOUT is not applied when deploying app on Heroku

Tags: heroku, config

My goal is to deploy an app on Heroku for the environment 'heroku_production'.

My Gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.9'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development, :test, :production do 
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
# This is needed in case this app is deployed in Heroku - in order to make the Heroku deployment independent from the production environment
group :heroku_production do
  gem 'pg'
end
...
```

I set the BUNDLE_WITHOUT variable to "development:test:production". Here is the output when calling `heroku config --app my_app`:

```
=== my_app Config Vars
BUNDLE_WITHOUT:             development:test:production
DATABASE_URL:               postgres://XXXXXXX....
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_CYAN_URL: postgres://XXXXXXX....
RACK_ENV:                   heroku_production
RAILS_ENV:                  heroku_production
```

But when I push my stuff to Heroku the BUNDLE_WITHOUT var is not applied as you can see in the following error message (line 3: --without development:test):

```
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Using rake (10.0.4)
       ...
       Using pg (0.14.1)
       Installing sqlite3 (1.3.7)
       Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
       /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       checking for sqlite3.h... no
       sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
       or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
       location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
       *** extconf.rb failed ***

       An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

To git@heroku.com:my_app.git
 ! [remote rejected] 3dac67374c268d3bf9e051a6db39efc56ae81c76 -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

Why is Heroku doing that?
Googling didn't help as well.

Answer (score 3):

> Please note - for the time being, the Cedar stack does not support BUNDLE_WITHOUT.

From: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler#specifying-gems-and-groups

Comment: thanks for the answer!

Does someone know if Heroku is working towards fixing this?

Gerardo

Answer (score 2):

I recently contacted Heroku about this issue, and they say that BUNDLE_WITHOUT now works!

Here's the response I got:

> Hi,
>   user_env_compile is deprecated, but the functionality of this just became default for the Ruby buildpack - so you can use BUNDLE_WITHOUT config var.
>   I believe that you saw this article, but is that correct? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler#specifying-gems-and-groups
>   Seems like we need to update that document!
>   Best,
>   [name redacted]

Haven't tried it yet but will soon.